# DRUPAL: replace tags with icons

Tags: drupal

is there any plugin for Drupal, replacing tags with small icons (see the picture below, the icons are actually small circles, and the different colors are automatically generated.

I need to replace the tags with the circles, for each node, and the starting view.

Furthermore, when the mouse move over the tags, the tag title should appear as pop-up

thanks

Edited: SORRY, here is the image! :)
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/tagsIcons.png

Comment: Is it just me or is the image really missing?

Comment: I wanted that too and failed to find an easy solution. I ended up defining a custom field in Views and defining a fancy CSS style to it :).

Comment: Paul's right, we need the image you're referring to.

Comment: @mingos: I'm more of a web developer/programmer than designer so my approach would go for some additional code lines somewhere. Since there's no image yet and not knowing how many different terms are involved I can't really provide a simple solution but have a nice example I just finished last month: http://clearingstelle-eeg.de is a German Clearing House website which features six main topics (aka terms) shown as round images in the header.
On front page there're several nodes some of which are tagged by these terms and as you can see, the corresponding image is always shown below the teaser.

Comment: @Patrick: very nice, I'd love to achieve something similar on my sites :). Alas, I know little about PHP or jScript and I mostly do design :). I'll be watching this thread in case someone can provide an answer.

Comment: @mingos: yeah this is what I want. But the image can be simple (just a circle of a color. And most important the color should be automatically generated. I dunno how many tags, it might be I have 7, but also 20 25 tags.. (so 20.. 25 different colors, to be clear).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is the [taxonomy_image](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image) module.
I use it and it works very nicely.
I had to enhance it a little to do what I want inside a View, but other than that it answered my requirements.

Comment: can this module automatically generate a unique color for each new tag added ? I would like the circles be added automatically for my customer. thanks

Comment: Out-of-the-box taxonomy_image won't do "automatic" image generation.
On the other hand, I believe it can be developed to do something similar to your needs (combine Rules with a pre-uploaded list of images might do the work).
As a fareelancer, I can make it happen...